# Bus Error:10 with more indexes to go

Tags: c++, arrays, bus-error

I'm using 6 arrays of ints, each holding 256 elements. Pretty standard, I'd think.

The problem I'm facing is while I'm initialising all these arrays to be full of 0s, I'm getting a Bus Error:10. Each time in the 240th iteration of my loop.

Here's my header file...

```
class histEqImage {
private:
int histogramR[256];
int histogramG[256];
int histogramB[256];

int dashR[256];
int dashB[256];
int dashG[256];

void initHistograms();    
public:
//Other declarations here...
};
```

And here's the function that the problem is occurring in...

```
void histEqImage::initHistograms() {
//Ensure all the values in the histogram are at 0.
for(i = 0; i <256; i++) {
    histogramR[i]= 0;
    histogramG[i] = 0;
    histogramB[i] = 0;
    dashR[i] = 0;
    dashG[i] = 0;
    dashB[i] = 0;
}
}
```

And so each time I get to this part of my code, the program crashes, at i=240. Sorry, to specify a bit better, it happens in the `dashB[i] = 0;` line

It's vexing me to no end, I can't see where I'm going out of bounds of my array, and I'm not messing around with powers far beyond my comprehension in terms of dynamic memory.

Any help, would be helpful.

Comment: Could you show the allocation code too? You are using `new[]`, right?

Comment: These are just simple arrays, there's no allocation done at all.

Comment: No, I mean `histEqImage`, do you allocate it on the stack, dynamically, or as part of an array?

Comment: Ahh, right. Sorry. It's just declared in my main function `histEqImage pictureDisplay;`

Comment: Please show a self-contained compilable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the size of `histEqImage pictureDisplay` is 6 KB (assuming 32-bit `int`s), it might be too big for allocation on the stack. Try moving it outside your `main`, or allocate it dynamically.

If you move the declaration outside `main`, make it static to avoid giving it global visibility.

```
static histEqImage pictureDisplay;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Moving the declaration outside the main function and making it static appears to have done the trick. I wasn't aware there was a limit on how big an item could be on the stack, thanks for the help.